# Why do I get "Invalid web origin" setting up google client id

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-mirror-api

I'm trying to set up a mirror API service for Google Glass.  I turned on Mirror API in the google dashboard per the instructions in the glass developer website for Mirror API.

But when I go to create a Client ID for Oauth2, I get "Invalid web origin".

I'm putting in www.myserver.com/foldercreated, which exists in my server.

Comment: Don't forget to set http:// (or https://) prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your url's domain name as `Authorized JavaScript origins` such as:

> http://www.myserver.com

And your callback urls as `Authorized redirect URI` such as:

> http://www.myserver.com/foldercreated

Don't forget to set http:// (or https://) prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I was using www.myserver.com/glassfolder for javascript origins and that was causing the issue. Now I have it configured, I was able to get the user consent screen, but now I just get a blank page. Im using the github mirror-quickstart-php-master project.

Comment: I couldn't understand where you get blank page. On consent screen?

Comment: After I accept the Consent terms, instead of being redirected to a control panel screen like in the demo, I just get the blank oauth2callback.php screen